# How can I resolve an IP address to a hostname in Arch Linux?

Tags: networking, ip, hostname

What is the most concise way to resolve a hostname to a local IP address in Arch Linux?

Comment: Using the `host` command.

Comment: I coulnd't find that in the Arch Repo or AUR, do you know what package this comes with?

Comment: `dnsutils` (I googled it).

Comment: Thanks.  You are welcome to add an answer so I can close this question

Comment: I had seen that originally but found it to be the opposite of what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use either `host` or `nslookup` from `bind-tools`:

```
$ host 172.217.19.195
195.19.217.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer fra02s21-in-f3.1e100.net.


$ nslookup 172.217.19.195
Server:     192.168.2.1
Address:    192.168.2.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
195.19.217.172.in-addr.arpa name = fra02s21-in-f3.1e100.net.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `host` utility will return a string containing the resolved host name:

```
$ host 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer google-public-dns-a.google.com.
```

This ought to be fairly easy to parse in any shell script.  If the host name lookup fails, `host` exits with a non-zero exit status:

```
$ if ! host 8.8.8.1 2>/dev/null; then echo "lookup failed"; fi
lookup failed
```

This utility is part of the `bind-tools` package in Arch Linux.

Comment: There is no `dnsutils` package in Arch, it was replaces by `bind-tools` in June 2015.